# Using If condition to select data

Tags: karate

For my test case, i need to inject data both from json file and from another feature file (which in turn contains DB connection and returns data from DB). If, data is mentioned 'null' in json file, then the code should call **DB.feature** file and return a data. If, these's a data populated in json file, then the code should pick up that and ignore **DB.feature** call.

For this, here's sample **Test.json** file that i am fetching data from.

```
{
  "data": [
    {"service": null}
  ]
}
```

And here's sample code having conditions;

```
* json data = call read ('classpath:PP1/data/Test.json')
* def service = data.data[0].service
* def data = service == null ? 'ABC' : karate.callSingle('classpath:PP/Features/Service.feature')

* def Svc = data.response.serviceResponse.service
* print Svc
```

Now, this works if service is **not null** in json file. If **service is null, then run fails** since it cannot find `data.response.serviceResponse.service` (which is where my data is located in the response from **Service.feature** file)

I don't know how to achieve this. Could anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your run fails because of data in `data` variable will not be same for **null** and **not null** cases.

```
* def Svc = data.response.serviceResponse.service
```

so the above step will cause failure if your condition is **not null**.

Based on your question and few assumption here is a modified code that might work,

```
* json data = call read ('classpath:PP1/data/Test.json')
* def service = data.data[0].service
* def service = (service == null) ? karate.callSingle('classpath:PP/Features/Service.feature').response.serviceResponse.service : service
```